# How can I mute/unmute the microphone in my c++ code?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, microphone

I am trying to use a program `pocketsphinx` for voice recognition. But I want to mute the input sounds sometimes. How can I do it in my C++ code?

I am looking for the code to turn ON/OFF system's microphone. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Which sound system are you using? ALSA? Pulseaudio on top of ALSA? Find out which one, then either use `system` etc. to call `amixer` or `pacmd` with the correct arguments, or read up on the ALSA resp. Pulseaudio APIs.

Comment: @dirkt: I think pusleaudio on top of ALSA, cause I have `pavucontrol`. Do you know it's commands?

Comment: Google e.g. "pulseaudio mute source pacmd", or google for the sink (more frequently used) and do the same for your source.

Comment: It is operating system and sound system specific.I would fork a system command for that.